# Wordpress jQuery Multiple Uncaught TypeErrors

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've checked my Wordpress site and I think I have some conflicting plugins or something going on that's preventing some scripts from running. Here are the errors from the console,

1. Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superslides is not a function
2. Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).doubleTapToGo is not a function
3. Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flexslider is not a function

Here's the individual code for each error.

**Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superslides is not a function**

```
jQuery('.max-hero').superslides({
      animation: 'fade'
    });
```

**Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).doubleTapToGo is not a function**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
if (agentID) {

    var width = jQuery(window).width();
if (width > 768) {
    if(jQuery( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).length)
    {
        jQuery( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
    }
}

}
else {
jQuery( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
}
});
```

**Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flexslider is not a function**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
```

**EDIT:** I fixed the problem, after seeing that the an html target for page jumping was interfering with jQuery in console, I deleted that and all scripts are working fine.

Comment: Can you share the link of the page?

Comment: Apologies for not putting it in the question, I've already fixed the problem. It was a simple target link for page jumping "#bottom" that was making jQuery not work.